# BitBucket: How to hide sensitive values in bitbuket repo

Tags: bitbucket, hide, sensitive-data

We have manifest file which contains some username and passwords which is being used by Jenkins during build and deployment.
We need to hide these values in repo when someone opens this file in browser.

Comment: What do you want to do with that encrypted property in log4j? Is it log4j2.xml?

Comment: yes it is log4j.xml. We are using external system for logs. It need to be loaded from manifest file during deployment.

Comment: Are you using log4j version 1 or version 2? The formats and configuration file names are different. Mule 4 uses version 2. And please add an example to the question (text, not screenshots)

Comment: We are using Mule 4, log4j.xml version 2.